# Is it possible to display ng-build progress in percentage only?

Tags: angular, build, package.json, ng-build

I am using angular. I know I can see the progress of my build process by adding the `--process` flag to my `ng build` command. Is there anyway I can get a progress bar that shows only the percentage without logging what is being built? I would like to see the percentage progress of my build process.